# ADO To Drop A Query

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado, ms-access-2000

I know you can use `Drop Table` to drop a table, but is their a way to delete a query?  I'd prefer to use ADO and not DAO to achieve this, if that is possible, as with DAO you have to open the database and ADO you do not.

Comment: Did you try `Drop query`?

Comment: Drop Query does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `drop view [queryname]`, i've not tried this myself, I'm pretty sure a "query" is just a "view".

Comment: [Try this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177897(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of query, use either `DROP VIEW` or `DROP PROCEDURE`.

`DROP VIEW` should work for a simple `SELECT` query.  Use `DROP PROCEDURE` with other query types.